# Samba quit working after router change - Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: samba, windows-7

I have had samba running for months as a fileserver. I have three Windows 7 PC connecting to the Ubuntu 23.10 samba server with read/write ability.

Last week, my cat knocked my Asus RT66U router off the wall damaging it. I bought another router from the same vendor, one model newer, Asus RT68U. Now, the three Win7 PCs cannot connect to the Ubuntu server saying the samba server rejected the connection. There has been no software changes on either of the Win7 PCs, nor on the Ubuntu samba server except for the usual updates via Discover.

I checked the smb.conf file and the workgroup is still the same as before the router change. Discovery is 'on' on the Win7 PCs. I can ping both the Win7 pcs and the Samba server from each other.

Can some one point me to a way to allow the Win 7 PCs connect to the samba server?

**Additional info.**
How is the samba server connected to the router. Wirelessly with a static IP.
I can ping the Win7 PCs from the Samba server and vice versa, I can ping the samba server from the Win7 PCs. I have 'discovery' on in the Win7 PC and can see the shares on the Ubuntu samba server.

**ip addr show data:**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b0:41:6f:0c:4a:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:5e:a9:c6:6f:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp2s0
    inet 192.168.1.40/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 77182sec preferred_lft 77182sec
    inet6 fe80::db76:3200:216f:cadc/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The static IP for the samba server is 192.168.1.40. The firewall if open for samba.

**Addition info, number 2**

Able to now connect to Ubuntu samba server.
I switched routers placing the original router back in service. I I took screen shots of the router configuration and both are the same, I checked page for page. I don't know why the 'new' router blocks connection to samba (all else, posix, dovcot, Apache. worked with both routers.

So. New router goes back to Amazon. Fortunately, the old router damage appears to just be superficial.

Comment: Please  add more information [in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1507531/edit). How is the Ubuntu Samba server connected to the router,WiFi, or Ethernet cable? Have you assigned a static IP address to the Ubuntu Samba server? If yes, have you done it by changing the settings in Ubuntu or in the router? Can you ping the Ubuntu Samba server from any of the Win 7 computers? Please enter the command `ip addr show` in a terminal in Ubuntu. Copy and paste the output into your question. Format the pasted output as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window..

Comment: Did you have the PCs' IPs specified in the router setup?

Comment: Did you have the PC's IPs specified in the smb.conf on the server? Like in the "hosts allow = ,,," declaration? New router - new DHCP - perhaps different IPs.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as the problem seems to b in the router, and not in Ubuntu. OP says reverting to the old router solved the problem.

Comment: I agree. It is/was a router issue. I've built a work around that's acceptable. I'm still working to discover why I can't SMB connect between the wired side of the router to the wireless side and vice versa. If I find the root cause, I'll add an update here.

Thank you to all who responded.

Crucis.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't want to look at the workstations or Samba setup, which makes sense, but you haven't provided details about the router either.  This is a Ubuntu forum so please provide complete details to receive the best help.

### Problem

What you're trying to do: connect to file share from Windows 7 computer

What happens when it doesn't work:

> Win7 PCs cannot connect to the Ubuntu server saying the samba server rejected the connection

### Explanation

NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED 
Meaning: The Samba server refused the connection request from the client.
Possible Causes: This error may occur due to ***misconfiguration of Samba settings, firewall restrictions, or authentication issues***.

### Understand The Problem

What do the logs say? - [ref](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Event_Logging)

> Viewing Samba Logs: The Samba logs are usually stored in
> `/var/log/samba/` directory on Ubuntu. The primary log file is
> `log.smbd`, which contains information about Samba file and print
> services. Additionally, there may be separate logs for individual
> clients under the same directory.

You can view the contents of the Samba log files using commands like cat, less, or tail. For example:

```
sudo tail /var/log/samba/log.smbd
sudo cat /var/log/samba/log.smbd | grep -i "rejected"
sudo cat /var/log/samba/log.smbd | grep -E -i "connection refused|CONNECTION_REFUSED"
```

**1st Guess: Ports Not Allowed** 
By default, Samba uses UDP ports 137 and 138 and TCP ports 139 and 445.  The easiest way to open these ports on Ubuntu is by allowing the Samba profile ([ref](https://www.linuxstart.com/install-samba-on-ubuntu/#:%7E:text=Samba%20uses%20UDP%20ports%20137%20and,138%20and%20TCP%20ports%20139%20and%20445.)).

```
sudo ufw allow samba
```

If you really want to get into the weeds you can test if the ports are open using nmap, PuTTYtel, or from command line after enabling telnet.  This should be overkill though and you can instead log into your router to check to see if it's disallowed, because the default config is probably allowing it.

**2nd: Re-build the Samba Share** - [ref](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-samba-server-file-share#:%7E:text=To%20check%20if%20Samba%20service%20is%20running%2C%20issue,be%20listening%20on%20UDP%20port%20137%20and%20138)
Sometimes troubleshooting takes way more effort than to just re-do something.  This seems like one of those circumstances.  Re-building the share won't affect your files.  So just run through the steps all over again.  Usually you end up learning more about the process anyways.  Pro Tip: document what you do.

**If you can ping, it's probably not Routing**
From Windows: `route print` 
From Ubuntu: `ip route list`

Ensure the default gateway is updated to the new router's IP address from all computers.  Test the route with `traceroute IP` (ubuntu) and `tracert IP` (windows).

**How To Connect**

From Windows File Explorer:

```
\\hostip\
```

From command line:

```
net use * \\Ubuntu_Server_IP\ShareName /user:username password
```

From Ubuntu Desktop: - [ref](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview)

If you don't have a spare computer you could just create a Live Boot USB flash drive, plug it into one of the Windows computers, boot to Ubuntu, and try connecting from there.  That would eliminate issues with Windows as the root cause.